# how to access ENV variables in index.html in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using ember.js, there is a requirement for us where we have to show a script tag(index.html file) only in production and not in development. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I know of to modify the index.html is during the build process using an in-repo addon.

Generate the addon with

```
ember generate in-repo-addon prodction-scripts
```

and then in `/lib/production-scripts/index.js` add:

```
contentFor: function (type, config) {
    if (type === 'head' && config.environment === 'production') {
      //inline this CSS so it is parsed the fastest
      return `
        <script></script>
      `;
    }
}
```